# Is GCP load balancers supports HTTPS and AMQP ports with SSL termination?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to know a few things with GCP Load balancers.

- Are GCP Load Balancers support HTTPS and AMQP ports with SSL termination?
- Whether GCP Load Balancers can forward requests to internal IPs?

As i am not familiar with GCP, Can anyone help me out on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad so I will point you to a relevant documentation here.

GCP support [HTTPS load balacing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https)

> Google Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancing is a global, proxy-based Layer 7 load balancer that enables you to run and scale your services worldwide behind a single external IP address. External HTTP(S) Load Balancing distributes HTTP and HTTPS traffic to backends hosted on Compute Engine and Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE).

and [SSL termination](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl);

> When using SSL Proxy Load Balancing for your SSL traffic, user SSL (TLS) connections are terminated at the load balancing layer, and then proxied to the closest available backend instances by using either SSL (recommended) or TCP. For the types of backends that are supported, see Backends.

[image]

Have a look at the general [overview of GCP's load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview) options - I don't know what your goals and requirements are but this should be helpful when [choosing your load balancing method](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer).

Answering your last question about forwarding requests to internal IP's - yes - LB's can and will do just that. Load Balancer can either terminate or forward your HTTPS requests.

If you need you can use it in the layer 4 and make it just a [simple TCP/UDP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network).

If you specify more requirements then I may be able to make my answer more detailed.